# How can I position and size my image Button

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy, I want to create my basic UI for android application,
and I tried to code down below, I first create my boxlayout to separate my UI into three parts: title part, main part, and icon part,
actually my question is about how to size and position my icon image button

```
<MyLabel@Label>:
    color: .8, .9, 0, 1
    font_size: 32
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

<MyBoxLayout>:    
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            text: "Face-Reg"
            font_size: 50
            color: .8, .9, 0, 1
            text_size: self.size
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, .8
        MyLabel:
            text: str ('Hello This is My  New Project ' * 100)

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 0.25
            Image:
                source: 'icon/server.png'
                size:self.texture_size
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 0.25
            Image:
                source: 'icon/add.png'
                size:self.texture_size
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 0.25
            Image:
                source: 'icon/recog.png'
                size:self.texture_size
        Button:
            size_hint_x: 0.25
            Image:
                source: 'icon/renew.png'
                size:self.texture_size
```

The output screen snapshot is:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HUXX.jpg) 
Four Icon are overlapped together, also the size is not match to the button size 
how can I fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the `size` and `pos` using those properties of the `Image`. For example, here is how you might adjust the third `Button`:

```
    Button:
        id: b3
        size_hint_x: 0.25
        Image:
            source: 'icon/recog.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size: b3.size
            pos: b3.pos
```

Note the `id` assigned to the `Button`. That `id` is used to assign the same size and position to the `Image`. The `allow_stretch: True` property makes the `Image` stretch to fit the specified `size`, and the `keep_ratio: False` allows the image to be stretched unevenly. See the `Image` [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html) for more details.